# I need to know how to make associated array of country and city

Tags: php, laravel

i need to know how i can make a array from db tables. i want something like that. i have 3 tables in data base country - state - city

data base structure is as follow

`countries`-table:

```
| id | country        |
|----|----------------|
| 1  | united kingdom |
```

`states`-table

```
| id | state                |
|----|----------------------|
| 1  | united westyorkshite |
```

`cities`-table

```
| id | city                 |
|----|----------------------|
| 1  | united wakefield     |
```

The expected result:

```
{
    value: '12',
    label: 'United Kingdom',
    children: [
        {
            values: '34',
            labels: 'West YorkShire',
            children: [
                {
                    value: '400',
                    label: 'Dewsbury'
                }, 
                {
                    value: '401',
                    label: 'Wakefield'
                }
            ]
        }
```

This is what I've tried:

```
$country_array = array();

$array = Country::select('countries.country', 'countries.country_id')
    ->isDefault()
    ->active()
    ->sorted()
    ->pluck('countries.country', 'countries.country_id')
    ->toArray();

// print_r($array);

foreach($array as $key => $arr) {

    $array_state = State::select('states.state', 'states.state_id')
        ->where('states.country_id', '=', $key)
        ->isDefault()
        ->active()
        ->sorted()
        ->pluck('states.state', 'states.state_id')
        ->toArray();

    foreach($array_state as $key_1 => $arr_1) {

        $array_city = City::select('cities.city', 'cities.city_id')
            ->where('cities.state_id', '=', $key_1)
            ->active()
            ->sorted()
            ->pluck('cities.city', 'cities.city_id')
            ->toArray();

        $array_state_1 [] = array (
            'value'    => $key_1,
            'label'    => $arr_1,
            'children' => $array_city
        );
    }

    $country_array [] = array (
        'value'    => $key,
        'label'    => $arr,
        'children' => $array_state
    );
}

dd($country_array);
```

I need these labels as well like value and label. i cant remove that as i am using vuejs element ui component.

I try to use normal foreach loop but its doing time out. any idea how i can do that in laravel using maps or collection or what is the best solution.

I am using php 7 and laravel version is 5.6

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Explain what your database structure is, and _show_ what you have tried.

Comment: West Yorkshite isnt a place - although maybe it should be!

Comment: @will its just dummy data

Comment: Do you have models and relationships defined between the models? For reference and help see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @teun yes its defined. but problem is i want a array in the format i told you

Comment: @WasiqAftab you can use the relationships and then at the end convert it to an array. So something like `Country::with('states.cities')->get()->toArray();` will give you an array with the states and cities nested in.

Comment: @teun let me try that. if it works but how i can change the keys. like value, label and children

Comment: Can you send me the city-wise, state-wise, country array, or JSON Format?
It would be a lot of help for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve all necessary data in a single statement, I would use nested with's. For example:

```
$result = Country::where('country_id', 12)
    ->with(['states' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('state_id', 34);
        $query->with('cities');
    }])
    ->get();
```

The next step is to modify the data. The map() function is indeed very useful for this purpose, although the nesting makes it look a little complex:

```
$mapped = $result->map(function ($country, $key) {
    return [
        'value' => $country->country_id,
        'label' => $country->country,
        'children' => $country->states->map(function ($state, $key) {
            return [
                'value' => $state->state_id,
                'label' => $state->state,
                'children' => $state->cities->map(function ($city, $key) {
                    return [
                        'value' => $city->city_id,
                        'label' => $city->city,
                    ];
                }),
            ];
        }),
    ];
});
```

Finally to display it, we convert the whole thing to a JSON array.

```
echo '<pre>' . $mapped->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . '</pre>';
```

Which gives me:

```
[
    {
        "value": 12,
        "label": "United Kingdom",
        "children": [
            {
                "value": 34,
                "label": "West YorkShire",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "value": 400,
                        "label": "Dewsbury"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 401,
                        "label": "Wakefield"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. but just one question here. how i manage the large database. like 172 countires than states and than cities. any optimizaiton idea about it

Comment: Try to retrieve the least amount of data by placing select's on all tables in the query.